# Computer doesn't seem to boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, power

A while back I bought a new computer. The old one was catching dust in the attic, but about a week ago, I saw it and decided to use it as a NAS, Network-Attached Storage.

I cleared it of dust, disassembled and reassembled it, and it should be ready to use. When I start the monitor up, the logo from the monitor manufacturer (LG) shows up, and I get a message which says "DSUB POWER SAVING MODE." The monitor is clearly working.

Then I turn the computer on, and I hear the fans running, but there seems to be no signs of booting anywhere. I checked the whole motherboard, RAM, processor and its heatsink, hard drive and wiring. I can't figure out the problem.

Does somebody know why it is not booting?

Comment: Do you get any POST beeps? Try a CMOS reset, or throw a new CMOS battery in and do a hard reset of the BIOS/CMOS using the jumpers on the motherboard.

Comment: I had no power on self test beeps, but I will try out a new CMOS battery, thanks.

Comment: Is the motherboard getting power? Can you try a different PSU?

Comment: He says the fans spin up, so unless they're 12V molex fans then I assume the motherboard is getting power.

Comment: I just replaced the CMOS battery(I had a spare one luckily) and did a CMOS reset, but I still get the same results, sadly. After I tried, I put the jumper back to it's default.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be getting beeps or flashing LED's if you get no video at power-on. I've seen this with RAM not properly seated among over things. Try to power it on with the minimalist hardware as possible: power cord & monitor; disconnect HDD & anything else inside that isn't required immediately. Still nothing, then power it on without the RAM, if no beeps/flashing-LED's there is something further wrong, validate processor seated correctly. All else fails I'd point at a faulty processor or CPU

Answer (score 0):

The best way to narrow down the reasons during troubleshooting is to disconnect all peripheral devices from the motherboard, as well as video card and RAM.
Leave only CPU with fan.

Start the PC: it should start beeping with long and short sounds (number depends on BIOS model) showing that RAM is not installed. If it's not beeping means MB or CPU failure. Also make sure you have beeper on the motherboard (round and usually back, can be also external one connected with 2-wire red/black cable).

Also, it can be PSU issues that doesn't provide *all* the required voltages or they are below than expected.

As a side test you may touch CPU fan to check if it's warm. It should be warm showing that CPU is powered. **Make sure you connected both power cables to the MB! (24+4 pin)**

All the next troubleshooting implies that you have knowledge in the computer electronics.  The easiest way is to use [POST card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_card) to check if MB and CPU start. It should code on LED display. IF its 00 - CPU doesn't start, all the other codes are MB issues.

If POST card is not available you need to use voltmeter to check the voltages on CPU VRM module, RAM slots, etc. Don't do it if you don't have proper knowledge.